# media queries not working when meta tag viewport is set

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

If i define viewport in my application as mentioned below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and media queries as mentioned below

```css
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
    /* Style here*/
}
```

then media quires do not work. but if i remove meta tag from html then media quires work perfect.

can anyone tell me why this is happening and what can be the fix?

Answer (score 1):

The **width** media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).

The **device-width** describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).

Main difference between them is that device-widths don’t always match the layout viewport of said device.

So, if you try to change you style to this:

```
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 414px) 
  and (max-width: 736px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
    /* Style here*/
}
```

You'll probably get working media-query on your device.

Answer (score 1):

Try for CSS:

```
@media only screen
  and (min-width: 414px) 
  and (max-width: 736px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
        /* Style here*/
}
```

HTML:
        `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
Your width equaling you device width is already noted in your meta tag, so remove it from your CSS.